# How to disable Raise-on-Click in Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, window-manager

**When a windowed app has focus and I click a maximized app below it, I'd like to set focus to the maximized window but for the windowed app to remain in the foreground.**

I recently upgraded (by means of a fresh install) from Precise to Trusty.
For a number of years my workflow has relied on "Raise-on-Click" being disabled. I like to be able to copy text from a maximized browser to a text editor or an IDE in a window on top of the browser.

In 14.04, disabling that setting has no effect.

I am used to do it via *compizconfig-settings-manager*, which is what I did:

[image]

I also verified the setting having changed in *dconf-editor*:
Under *org > gnome > desktop > wm > preferences*

[image]

Even though it should take effect immediately, I did reboot just to be on the safe side before asking here.

How do I restore my workflow?

---

***Edit: If this is not a global issue...***

... let me reformulate the question:
*What setting (in CCSM, unity-tweak-tool, dconf-editor) could possibly be overriding the above?*

Comment: It must be something on your system, here disabling raise-on-click works at once! (dconf editor / 14.04) Did you make other changes in compiz config editor?

Comment: May I ask why want this and why always on top is not what you need? (I hate ppl who ask question like this in SO sites so please hit me with a stick)

Comment: It is beyond me how one can critique a question when not having properly understood it, @redanimalwar. "Always on top" is a setting for *a single window*, while I am looking for the behaviour to be globally applied and in a different fashion. Clearly you have never used the above settings.

Comment: Yes, I did make one other change, I enabled the "Scale" plugin and bound it to the upper right hotcorner. But that I cannot see interfering. It didn't in Precise either.

Comment: You claim I did not understood the question, you also claim I critic the question. Both accusations are totally wrong. I am just curious what use case you have for this, how someone would benefit from that and in what way. I cant imagine anything.

Answer (score 2):

First check current state of `raise-om-click` option using `gsettings` by the command below:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences raise-on-click
```

The result would be `true` if you didn't disable it before.

Then if it was "true" then you can disable it by the command below:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences raise-on-click false
```

or If it returned "false" and still you don't get your desired effect then it sounds something is wrong or missing on your system.

From all apps that is from below setting:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences raise-on-click
```

Also you can type `dconf watch /` in Terminal and check the any changes from your settings.